Log-entries not color-coded when running tests
The log4j2.xml of this project reads:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Configuration>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="stderr" target="SYSTEM_ERR">
            <PatternLayout disableAnsi="${sys:disableAnsi:-true}"
                pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %highlight{%-5p} %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="${sys:logLevel:-INFO}">
            <AppenderRef ref="stderr"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
    
</Configuration>

This allows turning highlighting on -- and alter the log-level -- from command line by adding properties. It works nicely for us in the scripts. For example:
if [ -t 2 ]
then
    _JAVA_OPTIONS+=" -DdisableAnsi=false"
fi

However, when I try the same during testing: mvn test -DlogLevel=DEBUG -DdisableAnsi=false, only the first flag is effective: we do get the DEBUG-level log-entries, but the highlighting remains disabled.
If I add the -Dlog4j2.debug, I can confirm, that the right log4j2.xml is picked and that the properties are set as expected (note the disableAnsi="false") below:
DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %highlight{%-5p} %c{1}:%L - %m%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(/mi/sftdbaas/target/classes/log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", disableAnsi="false", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null", )

But there is still no coloring of the log-levels... Why is that?

Test output is encoded and sent to the main Maven process to print. Do you have ANSI escapes in the main Maven process (e.g. colored Maven logs)?

I haven't tried modifying Maven's own logging in any way. So the answer is, probably not...

The main Maven process recognizes the type of output stream you are connected. You lose colors if you: 1. use the -B option or 2. the output stream is not a terminal (e.g. it is a pipe).

Certainly not using -B. And the stdout and stderr of the mvn itself are both going to my xterm.
